# My laptop keyboard not working during installation of kubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, kubuntu

Trying to install kubuntu 22.04.1 on my new Asus Vivobook K3502Z. Using iso file from the Kubuntu official site and I make a bootable usb stick using Rufus.  The stick boots successfully into the 'Try Kubuntu'/'Install Kubuntu' screen. Then I notice that the touchpad does not respond to taps; I have to use the click button.  Then, when I click on 'Install kubuntu' it seems to check off on the left panel that language (English) and keyboard are configured? And it then goes on to the option to connect to wireless. I choose my hub and it prompts for the password. It's at this point I realise that I can't enter anything from the keyboard.  I also tried booting the stick again and chose 'Try Kubuntu'. When I load 'Kate' text editor I can't enter anything from keyboard.

Could anybody help with this one, please?

Comment: When you downloaded the ISO did you verify it was good before making the Live Media? This site will tell you how to do that. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Hi David, no I didn't. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting keyboard thru hub? And do you have full USB support or similar type setting on in UEFI settings. Many systems with UEFI Secure Boot also consider USB as not secure and may need settings.

Comment: In reply to David: Hi, I checked the ISO using the method in the link you gave and it checked out as a good ISO.

Comment: In reply to oldfred. Hi. In answer to your first question: no I'm not connecting the keyboard through a hub. It's the inbuilt keyboard of the laptop that I'm using.  I'm guessing your second question about full USB support only applies if I was using a hub for my keyboard. Is that the case? Or will it have a bearing on using a USB stick to boot and install the kubuntu?

Comment: Further info: I've just tried booting my old laptop (HP 15-ba077sa) from same usb stick. I chose 'try kubuntu' option and loaded 'kate' txt editor and keyboard works fine (I am using the inbuilt keyboard of the HP).  Taps, as opposed to using click buttons, on the touchpad did not work, though; but I think this was the case when I originally went through the install of 18.04 on the HP 15-ba077sa.  Taps then worked fine once it was fully installed.  Maybe ubuntu install program is having trouble communicating with the Asus keyboard.